# Trouble getting the day of week

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek

Having trouble getting the day of the week.  Today is Monday and it should return 2 as Monday is a second day in the week of the Calendar class. But for me it returns 7!!! Why??? the c.getFirstDayOfWeek() returns 1 as normal...

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("inside the loop +"+ c.getFirstDayOfWeek() + "    " + c.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` is simply a constant to be used with `Calendar`'s methods.

You will want to use `c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`

Answer (score 0):

It returns first day of week.
Eg: It Gets what the first day of the week is; e.g., SUNDAY in the U.S., MONDAY in France.
1-Sunday
2-Monday
and etc.,